# Using the "constraints" package to make a wrapped function less polymorphic

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, typeclass

I have this datatype:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneKindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

import Data.Proxy
import Data.Constraint
import Data.Kind

type Foo :: (Type -> Constraint) -> Type
data Foo c = Foo (Proxy c) (forall x. c x => x -> x)
```

It doesn't look very useful, but it's a reduced version of a datatype that is useful.

I want to use the [constraints](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints) package to write a mapping function over the constraint, using evidence of [entailment](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.12/docs/Data-Constraint.html#t::-45-):

```
restrictFoo :: forall less more. (forall v. more v :- less v) -> Foo less -> Foo more
```

The idea is that if the `more` constraint is stronger than the `less` constraint, it should be possible to convert a less constrained function inside `Foo` into a more constrained one.

I think the `forall v` is in the correct place. If it ranged across all of the signature, the caller would be the one who chose `v`, which seems counterproductive when working with the polymorphic functions.

This naive attempt at implementation doesn't work:

```
restrictFoo :: forall less more. (forall v. more v :- less v) -> Foo less -> Foo more 
restrictFoo (Sub Dict) (Foo proxy f) = 
     Foo (Proxy @more) f
```

It fails with

```
* Could not deduce: more v0 arising from a pattern
* In the pattern: Dict
  In the pattern: Sub Dict
...
* Could not deduce: less x arising from a use of `f'
  from the context: less v0
```

How to write correctly the body of `restrictFoo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, when you're unwrapping `Sub Dict`, there needs to be some `v` in scope to which the dictionary is going to apply, but there is none. So the compiler tries to create a fresh var `v0` in hopes to unify it with something eventually, but the eventuality never comes.

But let's think: where would that `v` ultimately come from? Well, what does unwrapping `Sub Dict` give us? It gives us a `less v` (for some as of yet unknown `v`), provided we can give it `more v`. And what is the place where we just happen to have `more v` and need `less v`? Why it's inside of `Foo`'s second argument of course!

So this means that we need to unwrap `Sub Dict` only when the second argument of `Foo` is actually called. At that point, whoever called it will have provided an instance of `more v`, so we'll be able to give it to `Sub Dict` and get out a `less v`.

So naively it would look something like this:

```
restrictFoo e (Foo proxy f) =
     Foo (Proxy @more) \x -> case e of Sub Dict -> f x
```

But this still doesn't work: the compiler doesn't know that the type of `x` is the same type that it needs to use for `Sub Dict`. There is no connection between the two!

To create such connection, we need to explicitly quantify over the type of `x`, and to do that, we need to give the new function a type signature:

```
restrictFoo e (Foo proxy f) =
     Foo (Proxy @more) f'
     where
        f' :: forall x. more x => x -> x
        f' x = case e of Sub (Dict :: Dict (less x)) -> f x
```

Now this works: whenever somebody takes `f'` out of the `Foo` and calls it, they will have to provide an instance of `more x`, and having that instance in scope will allow us to give it to `Sub` and get out a `Dict (less x)`, which gives us an instance of `less x`, which finally allows us to call the original `f`.

Answer (score 2):

You are pattern matching on `Dict` too eagerly. `Dict` provides the constraint `less v`, but it comes from a `Sub` which will give you `less v` only if you provide `more v`, which you don't yet have at that point; you don't even have a `v` so it's also too early to specialize that `:-` argument

You only get handed a constraint `more x` inside the second field of `Foo`, so pattern-match on `Sub` there.

```
restrictFoo :: forall less more. (forall v. more v :- less v) -> Foo less -> Foo more 
restrictFoo sub (Foo proxy f) = Foo (Proxy @more) g where
  g :: forall x. more x => x -> x
  g = case sub @x of
    Sub Dict -> f
```